# Homebrew is not working anymore

Tags: homebrew

I used to have Homebrew installed, but then at some point it broke, so I tried reinstalling it.
I tried running:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

It gave:

```
-e:70: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
    rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

(I don't know why it says it is installed, running brew gives "zsh: command not found: brew")
So I tried running that:

```
zsh: command not found: brew
```

Then I tried running it without `brew clean-up`. Which executed. I re-ran:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

It starts downloading and installing until it gets to this point:

```
Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Counting objects: 226839, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (59610/59610), done.
remote: Total 226839 (delta 165997), reused 226815 (delta 165979)
Receiving objects: 100% (226839/226839), 52.14 MiB | 135.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (165997/165997), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
warning: unable to access 'bin/.gitattributes': Permission denied
error: unable to create file bin/brew (Permission denied)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.
Failed during: git reset --hard origin/master
```

Tried adding sudo:

```
sudo ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Gives:

```
Don't run this as root!
```

I don't know where to go from here. Can someone help me?

Comment: This seems to be purely an installation issue and a better fit for http://SuperUser.com?

Comment: @PaulSasik: I would argue this falls under the clause: "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming," but I do see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart your terminal after installing zsh? brew is possibly not loaded for zshell. Also you need to add usr/local/ to your $path in .zshrc zsh configuration file should be in the in root ~/.zshrc

Comment: Yeah, I've had zsh for a while (so I have restarted it). For a while I've been using virtualbox and haven't had a need for homebrew, but there are a couple issues I've ran into with virtualbox, and need to use homebrew again. Thanks for the response, though.

Comment: Also, usr/local is in the path.